# axios is not defined in vue js cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I installed axios using the `npm install axios` command this is my `package.json` dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

I registered the axios in my `main.js` file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

import axios from 'axios'
import App from './App'
import routerList from './routes'

Vue.use(axios)
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

When I tried to use axios in one of my components I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The error might be from any file. Check all places you are trying to use it and make sure you import it properly everywhere!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Vue.use` means adding plugins. However, `axios` is not a plugin for `Vue`, so you can not add it globally via `use`.

My recommendation is importing `axios` only when you need it. But if you really need to access it globally, you may like to add it to prototype.

```
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
```

Then you can access `axios` in vue using `this.$axios`

Comment: it says vue not defined

Comment: @Beginner yours are `Vue` instead of `vue`, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 27):

## Solution 1 (Not recommended):

In `main.js`, add this line instead of `import axios from 'axios'`

```js
window.axios = require('axios');
```

And remove

```js
Vue.use(axios)
```

## Solution 2 (Recommended Approach):

Using `window` is generally considered a bad practice, so you better use `axios` the following way:

1. Create a folder named `plugins` inside of your `src` directory.
2. Then, create `axios.js` file inside that directory. We will put all our axios logic here and use axios as a Vue plugin.
3. Add the following:

```js
import ax from 'axios'

// insert all your axios logic here

export const axios = ax

export default {
    install (Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.$axios = ax
    }
}
```

4. In `src/main.js`, add the following:

```js
import Vue from 'vue' // You can skip this line
import VueAxios from './plugins/axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios)
```

Now, you can use axios as `this.$axios` in your components. So something like `this.$axios.get()`.

Therefore, you can import axios with the following line:

```js
import { axios } from '@/plugins/axios'
```

Now, you can use `axios` directly in your store.

Or you can also use it as Vuex plugin:

```js
import { axios } from '@/plugins/axios'

const axiosPlugin = store => {
   store.$axios = axios
}

new Vuex.Store({
    ...,
    plugins: [axiosPlugin]
})
```

Now, you can use it as `this.$axios` in Vuex.

Comment: Don't know why it is getting downvotes. It does work! I just tried.

Comment: It does work, however, it is **always** a bad practice to assign variable to `window` unless no other choices are available. BTW, I am not the one who give you downvotes

Comment: @user3003238 Yes I know! Since he is not accepting any answers, I just gave him this solution.

Comment: Your answer works only for vue2. For vue3, you have to use ``createApp`` and ``app.use(VueAxios)``.

Answer (score 13):

Use following command to install axios

```
 npm install axios --save
```

After executing above command import like mentioned below:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

Answer (score 6):

Also install `vue-axios` and import in `main.js`

```js
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
```

Then in `main.js`:

```js
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

Now if I am not mistaken in your methods you can use for example:

```js
let uri = 'http://localhost:4000/tickets/add';
this.axios.post(uri, this.ticket).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: do i need to install that VueAxios from the npm?

Comment: what i mean is in this line import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Comment: i havent install the vue-axios do i need to install it?

Comment: `npm install vue-axios --save`

Answer (score 4):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

then inside your component you can start using axios like this:

```
{
    methods: {
        someMethod() {
            this.$http.get('/users').then(() => {
                // do something
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this line:

```
import {AxiosInstance as axios} from "axios";
```

Answer (score -1):

To use in **Vue Components**, install both **Vue Axios** and **Axios** packages

```
npm install --save axios vue-axios
```

In your main.js file, add the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
 
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

With the above solution, I never had an issue using **axios** in my Vue components with `this` keyword till now.

**Custom Javascript File**

However, I had faced issues using **Axios** in a custom JS file with **axios not defined** error.

Following worked for me in a custom JS file:

```
const axios = require("axios");
```

Usage example:

```
export default {
  fetchProducts() {
    return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/products`);
  },
};
```

Comment: This was usefeul for me thanks! I was working on a Custom JS and always get the error axios undefined but with this declaration const axios = require('axios') inside my Custom JS all the methods now worked just fine. BTW: I didn't install vue-axios, just using my axios globally installation was fine.

Comment: @yehanny I am glad to hear it worked for you. Hope this answer and your comment helps someone else get a solution as well. And yes, according to the app setup one may have using Axios global installation might be sufficient. +1

Answer (score -4):

Try this codes:

```
import axios from 'axios'
    Vue.use(axios)
```