# Axios is not defined in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I'm trying to fetch data from Wordpress API. My console throws me an error "axios is not defined".
Here is my post.vue component.

```
        <template>
        <div>
    <table class="table is-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Posted at</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                        <td>{{post.title.rendered}}</td>
                        <td>{{post.date_gmt}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <pagination :pagination="pagination"
                        @prev="--postsData.page; getPosts();"
                        @next="postsData.page++; getPosts();">
            </pagination>
        </div>

    </template>


<script>
    import pagination from './pagination.vue'
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.getPosts();
        },
        components: {
            'pagination': pagination
        },
        data() {
            return {
                postsUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
                posts: [],
                postsData: {
                    per_page: 10,
                    page: 1
                },
                pagination: {
                    prevPage: '',
                    nextPage: '',
                    totalPages: '',
                    from: '',
                    to: '',
                    total: '',
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {

            getPosts() {
                axios
                .get(this.postsUrl, {params: this.postsData})
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.posts = response;
                        this.configPagination(response.headers);
                    })
                    .catch( (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },
            configPagination(headers) {
                this.pagination.total = +headers['x-wp-total'];
                this.pagination.totalPages = +headers['x-wp-totalpages'];
                this.pagination.from = this.pagination.total ? ((this.postsData.page - 1) * this.postsData.per_page) + 1 : ' ';
                this.pagination.to = (this.postsData.page * this.postsData.per_page) > this.pagination.total ? this.pagination.total : this.postsData.page * this.postsData.per_page;
                this.pagination.prevPage = this.postsData.page > 1 ? this.postsData.page : '';
                this.pagination.nextPage = this.postsData.page < this.pagination.totalPages ? this.postsData.page + 1 : '';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I really have no idea what's wrong here, I installed axios, npm install axios,

Here is my main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import posts from "./components/posts.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;

Vue.component('posts', posts);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Can anybody help me with this? I don't see where i got wrong?

Thank you all

Comment: have u ran 'npm install axios --save' ?

Comment: Thank you, now I have error "Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined"?

Comment: You also need to import axios into your vue component.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374367/axios-is-not-defined-in-vue-js-cli/57567547#57567547

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `import axios from 'axios'` to your component. Better yet create a config file called api.js file in your src directory and add something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': "JWT " + localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
    xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Then in your components you import like this:

```
import API from '../api'
```

And do API.get instead of axios.get

This is benefical because:

- You do not have to change your base url in 30 places when you need to change it.
- You do not have to add the same headers over and over in your axios calls.
- You can have shorter urls in your calls like this:

  `API.get('foo/bar/')
          .then(response => {
  }`

Comment: is the axios package is listed as default? why not {axios} <----- not work?

Comment: Yes it is the default, if it were not it would not import. Conversely its not a named import so you can not import it using curl brackets which is only for named imports. Default imports can not be imported using the syntax for you named imports i.e. curl braces.

Comment: If it's a NUXT app, instead of importing axios in your components, you can access Axios from anywhere in your application by calling `this.$axios.method` or `this.$axios.$method`. Where method can be `get`, `post`, or `delete`.